# Weird clipping with the 3D effect of Revolution Slider

Tags: wordpress, slider, revolution-slider

The Wordpress plugin Revolution Slider has a cool 3D effect with parallax. [See here in action](https://revolution.themepunch.com/wordpress-3d-scene/). My problem is that there is a weird clipping of the images and texts when moving the mouse to the sides of the page. Any ideas?

[image: Weird clipping 1]
[image: Weird clipping 2]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have enabled the 3D background in the Slider Settings (I have disabled the option `3D Background Disabled` in fact).

If you don't want the background to move, change the `Default 3D Depth` to **0**.

[image]